# PhoneGap (web mobile app) - Transfer data between pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a PhoneGap application. If you don't know what that is, it's a service that allows you to build mobile-based applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I have an application, and I've come to a point where I need to transfer information from one page to another. The user chooses an option on the page, the application then loads a new page and based on their option it loads specific content.

Now I do already know a few ways of doing this, to name one.. local storage maybe. My question is, what is the most efficient way of getting information between these two pages? If this were PHP I'd simply using $_GET[''].. but it's not PHP, I'm looking for the best way to do this using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Any help here would be highly appreciated!

Comment: How do you change pages? just normal links, jQuery mobile, any other way?

Comment: There are more ways of storing data. Look into JavaScript's [webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/). [PhoneGap's implementation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html).

Comment: @MichaelKunst Just regular links.

Comment: Using localStorage is a good way to handle this kind of problem. You can also explore the possibility of query strings in the URL.

Comment: And for the one person that's voted to close, this question is not "off-topic" at all. I don't see why just because the question doesn't contain a piece of code it's not a valid question... this is an important part of PhoneGap development.

Comment: I'd say query strings will be more than sufficiant if you only have to pass one or two user selected options.

Comment: @MichaelKunst Thanks Michael, I'll look into them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. *You are using a service like Phonegap:build or Cordova:* You only gonna have one HTML-File where you continously hide and show the different pages. I don't recommend this one, but Phonegap:build and Cordova are great to create a package for all major phones, without headache.
2. *URL-Parameters* you could pass parameter over the URL to a different HTML-Page. This means you have to open all links with `window.location.replace()` or change the `href`-attribute on you anchors. In the next page you have to parse that URL, which is not as easy as in PHP.
3. *localStorage / sessionStorage* you can easily store data in the sessionStorage. With `sessionStorage.myObject = JSON.stringify(complexObject)` you can easily store complex objects to the session storage and read them back with `var complexObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.myObject)`. Those are available during you complete session and would be one of the easiest solutions so far.

Comment: Also, I should have said, I do have only 1 HTML file and I'm loading pages through absolute positioning (layering etc), do you think localStorage would be the best one? It's the only one I know off the top of my head, will it work fluently on all the devices?

Comment: If you have only one HTML file you can access all global variables from all JS files. And, of course, embedded JS. If you still want to keep it in localStorage or sessionStorage, this will work on all mobile devices which support HTML5.